# Batch file removal of old files

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to remove files older than 30 days under `builds\<BuilnNumber>\workflow\*.*`. I also need to remove files older than a year under `builds\<BuilnNumber>\htmlreports\*.*`, if they exist.

How do I do that?

I tried using `FOR /D /r %%G in ("*") DO xxxx %%~nxG`, but got stuck there.

Comment: Yes but I need a removal under builds\<BuilnNumber>\workflow, and not builds\<BuilnNumber>\other_directory

Comment: So change the value of the `-p` option to what you need. You also don't mention `other_directory` at any point in your question.

Comment: Perhaps you could turn to [[tag:powershell]] for your task, you could even do that from a [[tag:batch-file]]. I prefer using PowerShell, especially for the case of your older than one year stipulation, where you shouldn't be assuming a specific number of days, for example: `…| Where-Object {$PSItem.LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddYears(-1)} |…`. As an example of your thirty days threshold, you'd change your filtering accordingly, e.g. `…| Where-Object {$PSItem.LastWriteTime -LT (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} |…`. _You can even exchange `LastWriteTime`, with `CreationTime` according to your needs_.